# C, Multiplication, Bit operation or *

Tags: c

I have to do many multiplication operations. If I consider an efficiency then should I use bit operation instead of regular * operation? If there is a difference how to do the bit operation ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you should use the multiplication operator and let the optimizing compiler decide how to do it fastest.

You will find that the compiler knows how to do this best for whatever platform it is targeting. What's more, if you start writing bit shift operations instead of multiplication or division your code will rapidly become unmaintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Prioritize readability over code optimization and let the compiler do it for you.

Don't try and get clever with the binary because:

- it probably won't be faster anyway
- you're much more likely to screw something up if you don't know how to actually do the bit operations

Answer (score 2):

No, for two big reasons:

1. Your hardware likely has built-in support for multiplication. This built-in support will likely be significantly faster than anything you could implement in software. Even if there's no hardware support, likely the compiler has a pre-defined algorithm which has been well thought out and guaranteed to work.
2. Unless you're very good with bitwise logic and multiplication algorithms, you're very likely to make a mistake, not to mention lots of time spent trying to implement it correctly.

There are only a few situations where I could think of that you may even begin to think of a custom solution:

1. You're implementing your own number representation schematic (very rare, but I have seen it done, particularly with legacy code)
2. You're implementing a "big-number" data type. However, again this is very difficult to do well, it's much better to find a library with one already implemented.
3. You're doing a simple multiply by 2^n using bitwise shifts, though this should be used sparingly (I usually only do this when looking to improve readability, not for speed improvements)

Answer (score 1):

bit operations can be used only to multiply a number with a power of 2 using the << operator (shift bitwise)

I remember there are other ways to improve multiplication like precomputing ths product and storing in matrix but all those will depend on your requirement in your application.

Comment: bitwise operators can be used to multiply any two numbers (actually, perform any operations on any two numbers). However, the degree of complexity is quite high when not multiplying by 2.

Comment: @helloworld922 Does it really have a performance gain if not multiplying by 2 or it is just done for obfuscation or for fun?

Comment: likely just for fun, though I have seen some useful (albeit strange) legacy code for multiplying two numbers represented in a non-standard format (such as trying to pack 2 or 3 numbers along with 4-5 flags into a 32 bit field).